# How to find value of tag which has multiple instances in same XML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have the following XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pdfDetails>
    <Menu menuTitle="AllTools">
        <pdf1>
            <tag>
                <title>Integrated Architecture1</title>
            </tag>
            <title>Integrated Architecture10</title>
            <description>details</description>
            <fileName>tools_selection_wizard.pdf</fileName>
            <imageName>icon_Image.png</imageName>
        </pdf1>
    </Menu>
</pdfDetails>
```

I want title *"Integrated Architecture10"*, but when I wrote code like:

```
$(d).find('pdfDetails').each(function () {
    var data = $(this).find('Menu');
    //iterate over childern of Menu tag
    $(data).children().each(function(){
        var title= $(data).find('title').text();
        console.log(title);
     });
});
```

It gives me output as:

> Integrated Architecture1Integrated Architecture10

but I want only

> Integrated Architecture10

How would I get it?

Answer (score 0):

In the inner loop, you reference `data`, while you should really reference `this`. And since `this` already refers to the `pdf1` element, you just need the `title` filter on the `children` collection:

```
    var title= $(this).children('title').text();
```

```js
var d = $.parseXML(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pdfDetails>
    <Menu menuTitle="AllTools">
        <pdf1>
            <tag>
                <title>Integrated Architecture1</title>
            </tag>
            <title>Integrated Architecture10</title>
            <description>details</description>
            <fileName>tools_selection_wizard.pdf</fileName>
            <imageName>icon_Image.png</imageName>
        </pdf1>
    </Menu>
</pdfDetails>`);

$(d).find('pdfDetails').each(function () {
    var data = $(this).find('Menu');
    //iterate over childern of Menu tag
    $(data).children().each(function(){
        var title = $(this).children('title').text();
        console.log(title);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```